How do ERC-4337 bundlers get UserOps from a private alt mempool?
I got to see a post on ERC-4337 alt mempool Is EIP4337 UserOperation mempool a P2P decentralized mempool?
Am having the same question, I want to create bundlers for my app and want them to only receive Userops from my app users and not any other userops from other Smart accounts. So I thought of using the alt mempool ERC7560 implementation by eth-inifinitism  https://github.com/eth-infinitism/bundler
In the code is see that the bundler listens to JSON-RPC for methods of type "aa_getRip7560Bundle" and then adds those userops to its own mempool in local storage.
My questions are

Same a the one in the Original post,is the alt mempool distributed i.e P2P ?
Even if the alt pool is distributed(p2p) how do i make sure that my bundler services only my app's userops and not any other. Is there a topic my app has to send along with userop structure for the bundler to listen to from the node client on JSON-RPC?

